# I would like to create in Android an individual thread for each activity launched from each button. Is that possible? How could be?

Tags: android, multithreading, button, android-activity

This is the piece of code where I want to insert the threads for each *Intent*.

```
public void onClick(View arg0) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
switch (arg0.getId()){
case R.id.artlistbtn:
    Intent openAL = new Intent(MainCore.this, MainActivity.class);
    startActivityForResult(openAL, 0);
        break;
case R.id.customslaws:
    Intent openCL = new Intent("slidenerd.vivz.FLAWS");
    startActivity(openCL);
    break;
case R.id.shouldknowbtn:
    Intent openSK = new Intent("slidenerd.vivz.KNOW");
    startActivity(openSK);
    break;
            }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

All Activities run on a single main thread, that is set by system and not you. However, you are free to create your own threads from within an activity and run some code there.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you should not perform this type of actions from a separate thread, you should always perform UI operations from main thread (and your onClick method gets executed on main thread) or (if you use a separate thread) - wrap this function in runOnUIThread call and it will result in execution startActivity/startActivityForResult on main thread anyway. Any idea why do you need a separate thread for this? startActivity/startActivityForResult are asynchronous calls, so they don't block your code.

Answer (score 0):

When `Android` executes your program, you are started with a single thread, your UI Thread. This is the only one that can communicate back with the android system service to tell you app what it should do, when, and how.

When you create a new activity, you do not create a new thread, you just add onto the existing one.

Sometime we need to run operations that may take a long time to execute, and need to operate on a separate thread, we can do that like this:

```
new Thread(){
    public void run(){
        while(true){
            //do stuff
        }
    }
}.start();
```

Where the thread will run separately, and not cause your app to ANR.

This thread will continue to run until it dies by completing a task, or is killed, however, if you launch a new activity, you may loose access to it, or miss a callback, sometime you need a thread to run for a while, and access it all across the system, the best use for this, and your problem, sounds like you want to use a `service`.

[See Documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html)
A Service is an application component representing either an application's desire to perform a longer-running operation.